# Magento. Add gender and Date of birthday to registration form

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to put 2 fields on user registration form, /customer/account/create/. Those fields are
gender selection and day of birth.

As I saw magento's customer module already has those 2 attributes, so If I don't mistake, I don't need to mess up with tables.

So how this can be done? Via observers? Or controller rewrite? What is better option?

My Magento is 1.5.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I only have a magento 1.6 version installed and there you have the options at:

*Configuration → Customers → Cusotmers Configuration → Name and Address Options*

Show Date of Birth
Show Gender

Comment: Nice. This is what I was looking for.